# Prevent Child component from taking style from Parent

Tags: angular

I have a component inside another which I'd like to style completely independently from the parent.  Current example being the text alignment;  I've set `text-align:center` in the parent but I don't want that to trickle down to the child.  I've tried the three different types of ViewEncapsulation (Native, None and Emulated) but in all cases the style is fed down to the child and the text is centrally aligned.   Any ideas how to deal with this?

Parent Component:

```
<div class="Home__Banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mt-5 mb-5">
    <app-mh-search-form></app-mh-search-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent Style :

```
.Home {
  &__Banner {
     background: url('/assets/images/homepage/mainImg.jpg') no-repeat center 
         center fixed;
     background-size: cover;
     text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```
<div class="MhSearchForm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="MhSearchForm__Nav">
        <div class="MhSearchForm__NavLink" (click)="setActiveState('buy')">
          BUY
        </div>
        <div class="MhSearchForm__NavLink" (click)="setActiveState('rent')">
          RENT
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The 'Buy' and 'Rent' text is center aligned, despite it being in a separate component

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? It looks like Native would be the option you want to wrap the child component in its own shadow dom, but hard to troubleshoot without being able to see whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your "Buy" and "Rent" text are inside the div with the .Home__Banner class, even if that class is for parent in CSS you are telling everything contained in the class Home_Banner should have its text align. To avoid this you have to set a style to your "MhSearchForm__NavLink" to set the text align to the left.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the point of View Encapsulation in that case.  I thought that child components wouldn't inherit any styles from the parent, but it seems to be the other way around.  A child selector can't affect a parent with ViewEncapsulation set to Native or Emulated